# Automatic count of rows stored in a PostgreSQL field

Tags: postgresql

I am creating 2 tables, one called `quizes` with:

```
id, quiz_name, plays
```

and the second one called `quizes taken` with:

```
session_id, quiz_id
```

and I would like to store count of rows, inside of `plays` column in table `quizes`, but I have no clue how to do it.
In more detail, what I am trying to achieve, is that on every update/insert into `quizes_taken`, in table `quizes`, the `play`" column updates with the row count of that quiz's ID from table `quizes_taken`.

If someone could explain how to achieve it, I'd be grateful!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would you want to store/update a static value, when you can simply _count_ the existing number of records at any time?

Comment: @CBroe how do I achieve that? Ideally I would want the static value to be automatically updated for that specific quiz, so then I can sort based on popularity.

Comment: Go read up on JOINs, if those don't mean anything to you yet.

Comment: Okay, I kind of understand how JOINs work, but now, how do I make the row's field to update depending on rows in another table? Do I need to use functions/triggers in that specific field, or is there another method?

Comment: You don't make anything update anything, you remove the `plays` column from the `quizzes` table completely. And if you need the count of responses, then you JOIN your data from both tables together and have the database _dynamically_ determine the count for you.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks, I will try that!

Answer (score 0):

you could make a view or materialized view for the expected result output,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW AS quizes_live_update AS
SELECT a.id , a.quiz_name, COUNT(b.quiz_id) as plays
FROM quizes a
JOIN quizes_taken b ON a.id = b.quiz_id
GROUP BY a.id, a.quiz_name
```

[Postgres: Create view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/sql-createview.html)

Although, if you need to proceed with tables approach, you can set up some upsert triggers
on quizes_taken table to perform update and insert on quizes table, plays column.